# Can't resolve resources

Tags: android

A few days ago I built an interface for an application I wanted to build and everything was fine, no errors. Today I re-opened the project (with the only difference being that I moved the project's physical location on my computer) and suddenly I'm getting a whack of errors, the first of which seems to be:

"Couldn't resolve resource @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin

The project isn't recognizing any of the resources under 'dimens' or 'strings' resources.

I don't know that there is relevant code to post because as far as I can tell nothing actually caused these errors.

I've read a few answers that suggest cleaning, refreshing, and rebuilding the project. I've cleaned (don't see a refresh option) and rebuilt, but nothing.

What is going on?

Comment: just restart your eclipse.

Comment: are you able to set target api for project

Comment: Strangely, I moved the projects back into their original folder (The Android projects folder, and the errors are gone). The cause seems to have been moving the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually was that I moved the original project into a different folder. Apparently creating the project in a certain location created a bunch of dependencies on it being in that location. Afterwards, after moving the folder back into its original location, I also ran into issues by cloning the project with a different exterior folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when there mismatch requirement of ADT version and SDK version

or errors in styles or manifest (like appcompatv7 not added properly)